# Sqlite running out of memory on a python call

Tags: python, sqlite

So, when I run my code, which is pulling a lot of data from a sqlite database,

I get the following error in my python code!

```
(<type 'exceptions.MemoryError'>, 'main.py', 427)
```

Yes, the above exception is some of my own error formatting.

Before it was just printing `MemoryError`

This is what I have on line 427:

```
rows=cur.fetchall()
```

Then I assumeed the problem has to do with memory: 
so I did the following

```
sqlite> PRAGMA page_size = 1073741824;
sqlite> PRAGMA cache_size = 100000;
sqlite> VACUUM;


sqlite> PRAGMA page_size;
4096
Memory Used:                         50186800 (max 100373936) bytes
Number of Outstanding Allocations:   12075 (max 24216)
Number of Pcache Overflow Bytes:     50045536 (max 100095168) bytes
Number of Scratch Overflow Bytes:    0 (max 11392) bytes
Largest Allocation:                  469214 bytes
Largest Pcache Allocation:           4244 bytes
Largest Scratch Allocation:          11392 bytes
Lookaside Slots Used:                0 (max 0)
Successful lookaside attempts:       0
Lookaside failures due to size:      0
Lookaside failures due to OOM:       0
Pager Heap Usage:                    49904696 bytes
Page cache hits:                     2011
Page cache misses:                   21561
Page cache writes:                   11780
Schema Heap Usage:                   7296 bytes
Statement Heap/Lookaside Usage:      1448 bytes
Fullscan Steps:                      0
Sort Operations:                     0
Autoindex Inserts:                   0
sqlite>


sqlite> .version
SQLite 3.7.13 2012-06-11 02:05:22
```

But I still get the same error.

Thoughts?

**EDIT:**

Per answer blow, attempted:

```
rows = []
while True:
   rows.append(cur.fetchone())
```

But the same result.

Comment: How many rows are there when you run out of memory?

Comment: After I do my query. the number of items in the list rows is 80776

Comment: How much data is in one row? Why do you need to store all rows?

Comment: Im comparing data from one row against all of the other rows. So, I need all of them. About 20 Columns wide. Is there a way to do this statically. Without having to pull it into memory. Looking at `htop`, I can see my ram max out before it crashes.

Comment: SQL can do comparisons. Edit your question to show what you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

The size of your database file is not necessarily related with the size of all the records returned by a query.

`fetchall` must load all results into memory at once.
You would be better off calling `fetchone` repeatedly and handling the records individually.